# In android how can I pass Arraylist<Float>

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist

In my application I am trying to pass ArrayList from one activity to another activity. how can I do that. please help! any sample.

Comment: I don't agree that it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

There's no method to pass an `ArrayList<Float>` as an extra, but you *can* pass a `float[]`. When creating the `Intent` to start your second `Activity` you'll need to convert your `ArrayList<Float>`.

```
float[] array = new float[arrayList.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
  array[i] = arrayList.get(i);
}
```

Then when you're starting your next `Activity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("floatArray", array);
```

In `NextActivity`, your `float[]` will be available in the extras. You can obtain it by calling

```
getIntent().getExtras().getFloatArray("floatArray");
```